# Show and Hide overlay using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am using JQuery for showing and hiding my overlay and it works just great. Now I also wanted to add some animations, hence I went ahead and check out the jq docs and got some nifty animations which can be applied to the show and hide functions directly.

What though I am looking for is on clicking, the overlay should appear to come up from the from the div which I clicked on, and on closing the overlay, it should hide by minimizing into the div which was used to open it.

Thanks

[Fiddle URL if you can show it here](http://jsfiddle.net/HfKTA/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HfKTA/1/ - Guess this is what you are looking for.

Updated fiddle with multiple triggers: http://jsfiddle.net/HfKTA/2/

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I am looking for. I will need some time to wrap my head around it though. Prefer writing vanilla js mostly :)

Comment: Could you explain me the animate function here. I am trying to replicate this for hiding. So I am presuming that ov.css is the initial state and .animate is the final state. But I don't get the second animation in the same way i.e closing into the div.

Comment: Exactly, `.css()` is for setting the initial state before animation. Once set, we `.show()` it and then call `.animate()` to animate it to full width and height.

Comment: For hiding, you can do the same by reversing the parameters of `.css()` and `.animate()`. Also, you'll need to put `.hide()` (instead of `.show()`) after the `.animate()` call to ensure that the animation is visible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Could you please verify if this would be the correct method to do it? http://jsfiddle.net/HfKTA/6/